# something to change text every some seconds in PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a `PHP` . Now i have div with particular class inside `file.php`. Now I want to automatically loop through some given values from array to be printed in that div after given interval of time,for eg 5 seconds.

Comment: can u explain in detail as I've just started php and working on my first project. I don't know much.

Comment: PHP is only used on the server side. If you want something that interacts with the user's browser (dynamic text, dynamic style, ...), you need to use javascript.

Comment: Agreed, you need JavaScript to achieve this, not PHP. PHP only runs on the server when the page is being loaded.

Comment: @JoffreySchmitz that's what I want to know..help please..how to link js with the file.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JavaScript requirement, here is an example on how to use JS to implement your needs in your PHP website, please copy paste this script below in your PHP or HTML file and test it.

```
<div class="output"></div>
<script>
const your_Array = [
  "Test 1 ",
  "Test 2",
  "Test 3",
  "Test 4",
  "Test 5",
];
const INTERVAL = 1000;  // in milliseconds
your_Array.forEach((item, index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementsByClassName("output")[0].innerText = item;
    }, INTERVAL * index);
});
</script>
```